# Google Spreadsheet auto selecting an item from range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, range

I have defined a range and two cells are displaying this range as drop down. User can manually select. But I want to write a script that allows me to select a particular item on these cells by click of button. I created a shape and wired it to this function.

```
function clear4u() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Calc_Max');
  sheet.getRange('C27:C28').set ..// im lost here
}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding what you are trying to do, I think you would need 2 methods. One for `button_1` and another for `button_2`:

```
function button1() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Calc_Max');
  var item = sheet.getRange('C27').getValue();

  // Pressing button_1 writes the value of `C27` to `E27`
  sheet.getRange('E27').setValue('item');
}

function button2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Calc_Max');
  var item = sheet.getRange('C28').getValue();

  // Pressing button_2 writes the value of `C28` to `E28`
  sheet.getRange('E28').setValue('item');
}
```